# How to select multiple images from gallery in Android

Tags: android

```
fun openGallery(index: Int) {
    var intent = Intent()
    intent.type = "image/*"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), index)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) return

    val pack = location.packagesList[requestCode]
    val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    pack.uriList[id] = data?.data.toString()
    adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    loadLocationToDB()
    loadPhotosToDB(data?.data.toString(), pack, id)
}
```

it doesn't work for me and I've tested on different phones.

I want to select more than one image from gallery, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you share `onActivityResult()` code

Comment: There is no requirement for any `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activity to honor `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`. You can *ask* for multiple images, but whether the user is *able* to select multiple images is up to the developers of the "gallery" app, not you or I. Still, you might try removing `createChooser()` and see if that impacts your results.